# Xcode 4.2 doesn't output exit code?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

Since updating to iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2, it appears that Xcode no longer prints `"Program ended with exit code: #"` on completion of a run.  Has anyone else noticed this and is there any way to enable it again?  I have an automated testing tool that relies on this output to determine if tests pass or not, so it would be very helpful to have it back.

UPDATE: I looked into this in more detail, and it seems to be a deeper problem. It appears that whenever I run an app, it crashes with a segmentation fault on exit. Sometimes this occurs just before the exit code is printed, sometimes right after, which is why the exit code message appears inconsistently. The seg fault message appears in the device's console, though there is nothing in the Xcode debug output.

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed this too.  It seems that in Xcode 4.1 (`tty /dev/ttys000`) `gdb` is started like this:

```
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
```

But in Xcode 4.2 - No `tty /dev/ttys000`:

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
```

*To fix this* you can do the following from a command line (Terminal.app/iTerm/etc):

```
echo 'tty /dev/ttys000' >> ~/.gdbinit
# Or, put it into the global gdb config:
# echo 'tty /dev/ttys000' >> /etc/gdb.conf
```

Then restart Xcode, and you have your exit code back!

---

Seems that Xcode 4.2's gdb wrapper has changed since 4.1

```
[ 13:29 Jonathan@MacBookPro / ]$ ls -l /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB /Developer-4.2/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB 
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  351936 Sep 20 13:23 /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  353776 Oct  8 14:21 /Developer-4.2/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB

[ 13:33 Jonathan@MacBookPro / ]$ ls -l /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/DebuggerGDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerGDB /Developer-4.2/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/DebuggerGDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerGDB
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  1976144 Sep 20 13:23 /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/DebuggerGDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerGDB
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  1948240 Oct  8 14:21 /Developer-4.2/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/DebuggerGDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerGDB
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to retract this statement. At first that seemed to work, but now it just seems to be inconsistent. Sometimes the exit code appears, sometimes it doesn't, with no pattern that I can find. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jeff Try putting it in the global gdb config like this `echo 'tty /dev/ttys000' >> /etc/gdb.conf`

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's still inconsistent. It's just that last line; I'm getting all the other output I expect.

Comment: @Jeff `/dev/ttys000` might be the wrong `tty`, run `ls -l /dev/ttys*` from a terminal and see which one is owned by you.  It could be `/dev/ttys001` or `/dev/ttys002`.

Comment: I looked into this in more detail, and my problem seems to be unrelated to the tty.  See edited question for more details.